# How to loop a certain number of times regardless the number of records received (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following queries :

```
      @php
     $age_id = \App\Goalage::where('goal_id',$cat_fil->id)->pluck('age_id');
     $age_name = \App\Age::wherein('rangeid',$age_id)->groupby('rangeid')->get();
     @endphp
```

And the following If condition and foreach :

```
                   @if(count($age_name) > 4 ) 
                           @foreach($age_name as $agename)
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm-new mr-1"> 
                         {{$agename->agerange}} yrs
                        </button>
                          @endforeach
                     <a href="{{some.route}}">Click here for more than 4 results <a>
                  @else
                  //same code but will show 4 results or less

                   @endif
```

How do I change the below syntax to only loop/show the first 4 results in the foreach, even if there was more?

```
@foreach($age_name as $agename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to break the loop after 4 iterations

Add this in the `foreach` loop

```
  @if($loop->iteration > 4)

    @break

  @endif
```

Alternatively You can do this in your case for Laravel 5.2

```
@php
    $count = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($age_name as $agename)
    @if($count >= 4 )
        @break
    @endif
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm-new mr-1"> 
    {{$agename->agerange}} yrs
    </button>
    @php
     $count++;
    @endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: I added this before the end of the foreach : if($agename->iteration > 4  , break  , endif , but still showing more than 4

Comment: If it is before the end of the foreach then it won't be reached until the end of the 5th iteration. You would want it before anything else in your foreach loop.

Comment: I added it in the beginning, but it is just ignored, and still receiving 7+ results.

Comment: seems that $loop->iteration is not working because I'm using Laravel 5.2. Any alternative solution ?

Comment: @AbdallahSakre Yes there is way but not good looking, anyway I'm updating my answer check it once

Comment: @AbdallahSakre I've updated my answer check it once above

Comment: @AbdallahSakre Bro actually I forgot one thing which I added just  now, Please check code again !

Comment: @AbdallahSakre Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `take()` or `limit()` to extract certain amount of records from the query:

```
$age_name = \App\Age::wherein('rangeid',$age_id)->groupby('rangeid')->take(4)->get();
```

Or

```
$age_name = \App\Age::wherein('rangeid',$age_id)->groupby('rangeid')->limit(4)->get();
```

**Edit:**

Use `$loop->iteration` to get the current iteration of the loop and break when it reaches a certain iteration which in your case is *4*.

```
@if(count($age_name) > 4 ) 
  @foreach($age_name as $agename)
      @if($loop->iteration > 4)
          @break;
      @endif
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm-new mr-1"> 
      {{$agename->agerange}} yrs
      </button>
  @endforeach
      <a href="{{some.route}}">Click here for more than 4 results <a>
@else
   //same code but will show 4 results or less
@endif
```

Comment: This will always send 4 or less to the foreach, which isn't what I need.

Comment: @AbdallahSakre Why send more than 4 records if you only need 4, its just a waste of resources and time.

Comment: There is an if/else condition, where if they are more than 4, then show a button, else, just show the incoming 4.

Comment: @AbdallahSakre Edited answer

Comment: seems that $loop->iteration is not working because I'm using Laravel 5.2. Any alternative solution ?